# Insertion of row in DefaultTableModel give an error if comes to isertion after sorting JTable Column data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter, tablerowsorter

In my appliation i have applied TableRowSorter to my JTable row sorting is working properly, the code for Row Sorter is given.

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(tableModel);
tableMain.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

I have JTree and JTable in my Application, JTree contain the Folders and Jtable show the data (files and sub folders information) of selected folder from JTree Node. When I click on a Node from JTree it will populate JTable properly the code to populate JTable is given below

```
public void populateTable(Vector<FileData> vList)
{
    treePath = treeMainView.getSelectionPath();

    FileData metaData;
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/folder.png");

    dtModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements();

    for (int i = 0; i < vList.size(); i++)
    {
        Vector v = new Vector();
        metaData = (FileData) vList.get(i);
        if (metaData.isIsdirectory()) {
            v.add(icon);
        } else {
            v.add(UtilClass.getIcon(metaData.getClientpath()));
        }
        v.add(metaData.getName());
        v.add(metaData.getClientpath());
        if (metaData.isIsdirectory())
        {
            v.add("");
        }
        else
        {
            v.add((FileHelper.getSizeString(metaData.getSize())));
        }
        if (metaData.isIsdirectory()) {
            v.add("");
        }
        else
        {
            v.add(new Date(metaData.getTime()));
        }
        if (metaData.isIsdirectory()) {
            v.add("Folder");
        } 
        else
        {
            v.add(UtilClass.getIcon(metaData.getClientpath()));
        }



        tableModel.insertRow(i, v);

    }
    tableMain.repaint();
}
```

The issue arrise when I sort any of colum from JTable and come back to JTree and click on some othe node to see its detail then the exception will occure and JTree is hide exception is given below

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:632)
at javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter$TableRowSorterModelWrapper.getValueAt(TableRowSorter.java:252)
at javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter$TableRowSorterModelWrapper.getStringValueAt(TableRowSorter.java:268)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.compare(DefaultRowSorter.java:935)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.access$100(DefaultRowSorter.java:95)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter$Row.compareTo(DefaultRowSorter.java:1359)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter$Row.compareTo(DefaultRowSorter.java:1349)
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch0(Arrays.java:2001)
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Arrays.java:1943)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.insertInOrder(DefaultRowSorter.java:983)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsInserted0(DefaultRowSorter.java:1041)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsInserted(DefaultRowSorter.java:851)
at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(JTable.java:4267)
at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4115)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4392)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:280)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsInserted(AbstractTableModel.java:215)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(DefaultTableModel.java:359)
at org.mycom.gui.MyClass.populateTable(MyClass.java:5866)
at org.mycom.gui.MyClass$Selection.valueChanged(MyClass.java:5753)
at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(JTree.java:2820)
at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(JTree.java:3191)
at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:629)
at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1078)
at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:287)
at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:170)
at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(JTree.java:1598)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(BasicTreeUI.java:2316)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(BasicTreeUI.java:3525)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTreeUI.java:3464)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:262)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6213)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5981)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4583)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4413)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4217)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4150)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4413)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: incorrect usage of the model: never-ever change the underlying data structure! Instead, _always_ use model api. In your code snippet you mix both (remove from the underlying vector without notification of the listeners, insert via the model). Note: it is _never_ necessary to call repaint on the view - if that magically seems to solve something, you have a serious problem somewhere, typically a missing/incorrect notification.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in [*How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), `JTable` view coordinates are *not* identical to `TableModel` model coordinates. `JTable` provides methods that convert between the two, which may be required in this context. One symptom is a table that does not correctly handle reordering columns by dragging.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    table.convertColumnIndexToModel(viewColumnIndex)
    table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRowIndex)
```

To retrieve the actual row or column you want.